# Apply a transparent circle to a flash movieclip

Tags: flash, actionscript, transparency, alpha

Is there a way to make part of a movieclip transparent? Using actionscript that is.
I want to create 'holes' in a movieclip so I can see through it.

If needed I guess I can change the movieclip into a sprite if that makes it easier, but I am unfamiliar with flash so I need to learn the proper way to do such a thing.

My thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using the [`mask`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#mask) property

Answer (score 3):

You can also check out `BlendMode.ERASE` on the `blendMode` option for a `DisplayObject`: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#blendMode

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you need, nothing too fancy required:

```
var s:Sprite = new Sprite(); // create a sprite to holder your image.
s.addChild(myImage); // add your image
addChild(s); // add your sprite to the stage.

var masker:Sprite = new Sprite(); // create a second sprite to be the mask
masker.graphics.beginFill(0x000000); // draw the shapes you want to use as masks
masker.graphics.drawCircle(50, 50, 100); // ...for instance, this circle
masker.graphics.endFill();
addChild(masker); // add your masker to the stage

s.mask = masker; // set the mask property of your image holder to be the masker
```

That should do what you need. Let me know if you have any further questions!